# Does ERC20's transferFrom function fail if it doesn't meet the require statement?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-20-approve

I'm learning about the ERC20 contract by OpenZeppelin and curious about the approve function:

```
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);

        return true;
    }
```

Logically, it would make sense that you're only able to transfer `amount` from `sender` to `recipient` **only if** `currentAllowance >= amount`.

However, as you can see in this function body, the `require(currentAllowance >= amount)` occurs **after** the call to `_transfer(sender, recipient, amount)`.

Now I remember reading that ethereum transactions are atomic. In this context, does it mean that if the require condition fails, then the call to `_transfer` is also not executed?

Comment: If the condition in `require` fails, Solidity performs a revert. See [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require)